# If checkJetifier doesn't throw warning, does that mean I can remove it from my project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetifier

I ran **build -> Make Project**, and then used the **Build Analyze**r.

Inside the reports, I select the Warning tab and no jetifier warnings are found. (The project is build with Android Gradle Plugin 4.1)

Does that mean that I can be confident that jetifier does not need to be used for any lib and I may disable the jetifier from the `gradle.properties` file?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, no.

Probabably it will only check direct dependencies or known dependencies. We use a vendor artifact that didn't throw any errors when compiling, running profiler, etc. But after running the app it threw exception because it was still requiring the `android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat` class